# Unable to resolve 'Untrusted XML should be parsed with a local, static DTD' in Sonar

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, stax

I had these blocks of code in my project (Java with Lombok):

```
val factory = (XMLInputFactory2) XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
val streamReader = (XMLStreamReader2) factory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
```

and

```
val factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
val eventReader = factory.createXMLEventReader(new CharArrayReader(marshaledObject.toCharArray()));
```

I analysed my code with Sonarqube (set up using this Docker image: [owasp/sonarqube](https://hub.docker.com/r/owasp/sonarqube)).

Both block of code have been flagged as vulnerabilities violating the rule `Untrusted XML should be parsed with a local, static DTD`.

I changed my code to:

```
val factory = (XMLInputFactory2) XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, Boolean.FALSE);
factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, Boolean.FALSE);
val streamReader = (XMLStreamReader2) factory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
```

and

```
val factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, Boolean.FALSE);
factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, Boolean.FALSE);
val eventReader = factory.createXMLEventReader(new CharArrayReader(marshaledObject.toCharArray()));
```

respectively and reran analysis. Both code blocks are still flagged as violating the aforementioned rule. I don't understand why. Should I set some additional properties on the factories?

My project is built with Gradle 5.3.1 and analysed using plugin `org.sonarqube` version 2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be false-positive in Sonar analysis, your code looks exactly as it should according to [Untrusted XML should be parsed with a local, static DTD](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2755) rule example.

When you confirm that `eventReader` is not vulnerable anymore you might want to add `// NOSONAR` to suppress a false-positive. As per Sonar Docs [Frequently Asked Questions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/faq/):

> **False-Positive and Won't Fix**
>
> You can mark individual issues False Positive or Won't Fix through the issues interface. If you're using Short-lived branch and PR analysis provided by the Developer Edition, issues marked False Positive or Won't Fix will retain that status after merge. This is the preferred approach.
>
> **//NOSONAR**
>
> Most language analyzers support the use of the generic mechanism: //NOSONAR at the end of the line of the issue. This will suppress the all issues - now and in the future - that might be raised on the line.

Comment: It is a false positive. In the second case, since the event reader is only used for XSD-based validation, the XXE vulnerability does not seem to be present even without the properties set.